# Create new session/window name that contain dot

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, tmux

I have a variable as below (all commands in this post issued in a shell bash/zsh):

```
var="test.abc"
tmux new-window -n ${var}-windows
```

in the new created window I issue this command:

```
var="test.abc"
tmux send-keys -t$var-windows "echo dafsd" Enter
```

I got the error: `can't find pane: abc-windows`

I try another command: `tmux send-keys -t test\.abc-windows "echo dafsd" Enter`, got the same error as above: `can't find pane: abc-windows`

`tm list-windows` does show as below:

```
2: test.abc-windows* (1 panes) [416x117] [layout 5154,416x117,0,0,15] @12 (active)
```

meaning `test.abc-windows` is created as expected but I can't seem to `send-keys` to it event with literal name `test.abc-windows` / `test\.abc-windows`

The same issue when I try to create new session name that contains dot as below:

```
var="test.abc"
tmux new-session -d -s $var-session -n $var-session
```

I got below error:

```
bad session name: test.abc-session
```

This time, session is not created (contrast to above that `test.abc-windows` is created)

Howto create new tmux session/windows that contain dot properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session names cannot contain either `.` or `:`.

You can create window names with them but you won't be able to use them in targets so I don't recommend it. You can still target the window using the window index (eg `:3`) or window ID (eg `@2`).

Comment: Guess I have to convert `.` to `_` to name with tmux.